# How can I use the {x:Static ...} extension for Phone7 Silverlight apps?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, static, constants

I'm writing a Phone 7 app and I would like to reference constant values in markup.  I believe the way one is supposed to do this is via [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx).

However, Visual Studio keeps claiming it has no knowledge of `x:static`.  What is the secret sauce here?  I have the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
  ...
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  ...

  <Image Height="{x:Static App.ImageHeight}" ... />
  ...
```

And of course:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  public const double ImageHeight = 100;
  ...
```

The error message is "The type 'x:Static' was not found. Verify that...".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`x:Static` is only available in WPF - neither Silverlight for the browser nor Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 support this markup extension.

The usual workaround is to create a (non-static) class that has properties which simply wrap the static properties you want, and create an instance of that as a Resource and bind against it that way.

Example*:

```
public class StaticSideEnums
{
    public static Side Bid { get { return Side.Bid; } }
    public static Side Ask { get { return Side.Ask; } }
}
```

In the resources (app.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:StaticSideEnums x:Key="StaticSideEnums"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the xaml where it's used:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="picker" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Buy"  Tag="{Binding Bid, Source={StaticResource StaticSideEnums}}" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Sell" Tag="{Binding Ask, Source={StaticResource StaticSideEnums}}" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

*This example is taken from an answer in [Using localized strings in a ListPicker populated from Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594308/using-localized-strings-in-a-listpicker-populated-from-enum/21763543#21763543)

Comment: Good point, and I'll fix that above.  However I get the same error.  Intellisense only gives me `x:Null` as an option when I type `{x:`.  I'm pretty sure I'm just not referencing something properly...

Comment: Okay, well, that seems like a lot of work to just have a constant.  But, okay, if that's how it is, that's how it is.  Thanks.

Comment: For your specific use case, maybe a Style would be better?  Then you could set the Height to anything you want once, use that Style on all Image elements, and get the same level of "change once, apply everywhere".

Comment: @Shimmy, why ? It's a correct answer, it was upvoted and accepted, I can't see any reason why I should change it to a comment...

Comment: @Thomas, my mistake, I meant to write my comment on an entirely different thread... comment deleted.

Comment: I've been struggling to execute this solution and i'd been getting worthless XAMLParseExceptions on InitializeComponent in the App class. Untill after 20+ minutes of searching for the solution I found that my variant of StaticSideEnums wasn't public. So I hope that you will add an emphasis that that class has to be public so others won't struggle with it like I did.