# Using localized strings in a ListPicker populated from Enum

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, combobox, enums

I'm populating a `ListPicker` from an `Enum`. For example, if I have the following Enum:

```
public enum Pets 
{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Platypus 
}
```

I populate the ListPicker in the following way:

```
PetListPicker.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pets));
```

Everything OK until there. My ListPicker control shows the names of items to choose.

The problem is that I want to localize that Enum items to use them in different languages. That is, I'd like the ListPicker to show the names in the language that the app is currently using.

I have the localizes strings in resource files, which I use to localize the rest of the app. However, I don't know how to make it to work with the ListPicker items.

Comment: I think you're looking for a [TypeConverter](stackoverflow.com/questions/796607/how-do-i-have-an-enum-bound-combobox-with-custom-string-formatting-for-enum-valu/796754)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have finally found an approach to achieve my goal using `Description` attribute for enum values and a `Converter`.

Since it is not possible to use the values from the Resources file direcatly as Description attributes, first of all I created my custom LocalizedDescriptionAttribute class, which inherits from DescriptionAttribute:

```
public class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(string resourceId)
        : base(GetStringFromResource(resourceId))
    { }

    private static string GetStringFromResource(string resourceId)
    {
        return AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceId);
    }
}
```

That way I can use the ID of the resource as LocalizedDescription attribute:

```
public enum Pet
{
    [LocalizedDescription("Dog")]
    Dog,
    [LocalizedDescription("Cat")]
    Cat,
    [LocalizedDescription("Platypus")]
    Platypus 
}
```

Once here, I created a `ValueConverter` which does the work of shwoing the string in the appropriate language in my ListPicker:

```
public class EnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Type type = value.GetType();
            string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            if (name != null)
            {
                FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
                if (field != null)
                {
                    DescriptionAttribute attr =
                           Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                             typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
                    if (attr != null)
                    {
                        return attr.Description;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Done this, I created a `DataTemplate` for the ListPicker items, setting the value of the Text property of a TextBlock by a `Binding` and using the `Converter`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListPickerDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I populate the ListPicker the same way I did it before:

```
PetListPicker.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pet));
```

Now my ListPicker shows the localized values of the items, with the advantage that the `SelectecItem` property of the ListPicker can be binded to a property of the type of the Enum.

For example, if I have following property in my ViewModel, where I want to store the selected item:

```
public Pet MyPet {get; set;};
```

I can just use a binding:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="MyListPicker" SelectedItem="{Binding MyPet, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerDataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: This is excelent solution!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to write a method that looks up the translated strings and returns them in an array. (You can also do it by adding attributes to the enum, but I personally think that's far more trouble than it's worth.)

What I mean is something like this:

```
public string[] TranslatedPetsEnum()
{
    string[] result = new []
    {
        Resources.PetCat,
        Resources.PetDog,
        Resources.PetPlatypus
    };

    return result;
}
```

Then you just do:

```
PetListPicker.ItemsSource = TranslatedPetsEnum();
```

If you just want to translate one enum value:

```
public string TranslatePet(Pets pet)
{
    switch (pet)
    {
        case Pets.Dog:      return Resources.PetDog;
        case Pets.Cat:      return Resources.PetCat;
        case Pets.Platypus: return Resources.PetPlatypus;
        default:            return Resources.PetUnknown;
    }
}
```

You could also implement `TranslatedPetsEnum()` using `TranslatePet()` which might be more maintainable:

```
public string[] TranslatedPetsEnum()
{
    Pets[] pets = (Pets[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pets));
    string[] result = new string[pets.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < pets.Length; ++i)
        result[i] = TranslatePet(pets[i]);

    return result;
}
```

(Also a small point: The proper naming convention should be to call the enum `Pet`, not `Pets`. Plural enum names are supposed to be used for enums which have values that can be ORed together.)

Comment: The problem here is that I cannot bind the SelectedItem property of the ListPicker to a property of type Pets. By the way, thank you for your advice!

Comment: I have finally solved the problem following other approach using DescriptionAttributes and a ValueConverter. I have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach in WPF, which does **not** work in Windows Phone is this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding Side}">
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Side.Bid}" Content="Buy"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static local:Side.Ask}" Content="Sell"/>
</ComboBox>
```

"Buy" and "Sell" in the content are independent of the Binding and are then localized in the same way everything else is. This approach does have different advantages and disadvantages compared to the accepted answer, so it may be of benefit to some people.

Because `ListPicker` doesn't support `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`, and Windows Phone doesn't support `x:Static`, this can't be done trivially in Windows Phone - unless you have a GUI library with a more useful `ListPicker` than the one in the toolkit. If your more expensive ListPicker supports `SelectedValuePath`, scroll down to see how you can work around the lack of `x:Static`.

A somewhat similar implementation can be done by skipping the Binding (or by binding to an in-between variable in the code behind for set/get):

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="picker" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Buy" Tag="{x:Static local:Side.Bid}" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Sell" Tag="{x:Static local:Side.Ask}" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>

void OnSelectionChanged(...)
{
    if (DataContext != null && picker.SelectedItem != null)
       (DataContext as MyClass).Side= (Side)(((ListPickerItem)picker.SelectedItem).Tag);
}

void Init()
{
    picker.SelectedItem = picker.Items.First(i => (DataContext as MyClass).Side.Equals(((ListPickerItem)i).Tag));
}
```

Of course that won't work becauxe Windows Phone 8 does not support `x:Static`. To work around that we need this little gem:

```
public class StaticSideEnums
{
    public static Side Bid { get { return Side.Bid; } }
    public static Side Ask { get { return Side.Ask; } }
}

<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:StaticSideEnums x:Key="StaticSideEnums"/>
</ResourceDictionary>

<toolkit:ListPicker Name="picker" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Buy" Tag="{Binding Bid, Source={StaticResource StaticSideEnums}}" />
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Sell" Tag="{Binding Ask, Source={StaticResource StaticSideEnums}}" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```